# Alternative term(s) for 'not my family', 'not my kin'?

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

I am looking for a term that describes not-family, or not kin. Other than not-family and not-kin. Ideally a term without a negation (not, no, non, sans...).

War and especially genocide is preceded by several rhetoric tactics and strategies. One of the primary is dangerous speech that is otherizing (eliminationism, dehumanization, xenophobia, demonizing, outgrouping, racism...), and a key part of otherizing is to separate family/kin from not-family/non-kin. For example: One tactic used in military boot camps is to condition soldiers to adopt a mental model that all soldiers in the same group are family/kin, since humans are well documented to be far more willing to die for family/kin.

**Example statement**: Rhetoric tactics are used to frame ________ (not-family, non-kin) as being in the 'not one of us' group — the cause of problems, not to be trusted, behaving in evil/immoral ways — and thus they must be avoided, controlled and possibly eliminated.

Comment: A standard term is *not related*.  You can also say *no relation*.  But you should include a sample sentence with a blank line where the proposed word would go.  Without that I can't say whether one of these two standard terms will work well.  How about editing the question?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have edited and added an Example statement ("sample sentence")

Comment: Okay, I think *outsider* fits well.

Comment: @aparente001 - You can use "unrelated" as an adjective (but generally not as a noun).

Comment: @aparente001 - Good point! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question. Some terms that come to mind are *they*, *them*, *other*, *outsider*, *foreigner*, *alien*, *intruder*, *interloper*. In worse cases, geopolitically, it is common for those in power to dehumanize the outgroup by calling their existence and presence an *infestation* or *pestilence*, and/or assigning racial or biological inferiority to the outgroup.

Comment: The question now includes an example sentence and this answer may need to be amended.

Comment: Thanks! Good suggested terms and inferiority framings. <br> I have edited my original post and added "Ideally a term without a negation (not, no, non, sans...)." and Example statement. 
Ideally the term(s) would be a term specific to family or kin